# Add Google Tag Manager to WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to add the Google Tag Manager to the header.php of my WordPress site but I can't seem to get it in the right location.

For some reason my body tag is super long.
I place the Google Tag Manager snippet after this line of code but it's incorrect.

I also tried placing it after directly after `<body <?php body_class(); ?>` but had no luck.

Any ideas?

Below is my body tag:

```
 <body <?php body_class(); ?>data-footer-reveal="<?php echo $footer_reveal; ?>" data-footer-reveal-shadow="<?php echo $footer_reveal_shadow; ?>" data-cae="<?php echo $column_animation_easing; ?>" data-cad="<?php echo $column_animation_duration; ?>" data-aie="<?php echo $animate_in_effect; ?>" data-ls="<?php echo $lightbox_script;?>" data-apte="<?php echo $page_transition_effect;?>" data-hhun="<?php echo $hideHeaderUntilNeeded; ?>" data-fancy-form-rcs="<?php echo $fancy_rcs; ?>" data-form-style="<?php echo $form_style; ?>" data-is="<?php echo $icon_style; ?>" data-button-style="<?php echo $button_styling; ?>" data-header-inherit-rc="<?php echo (!empty($options['header-inherit-row-color']) && $options['header-inherit-row-color'] == '1' && $perm_trans != 1) ? "true" : "false"; ?>" data-header-search="<?php echo $headerSearch; ?>" data-animated-anchors="<?php echo (!empty($options['one-page-scrolling']) && $options['one-page-scrolling'] == '1') ? 'true' : 'false'; ?>" data-ajax-transitions="<?php echo (!empty($options['ajax-page-loading']) && $options['ajax-page-loading'] == '1') ? 'true' : 'false'; ?>" data-full-width-header="<?php echo $fullWidthHeader; ?>" data-slide-out-widget-area="<?php echo ($sideWidgetArea == '1') ? 'true' : 'false';  ?>" data-loading-animation="<?php echo (!empty($options['loading-image-animation'])) ? $options['loading-image-animation'] : 'none'; ?>" data-bg-header="<?php echo $bg_header; ?>" data-ext-responsive="<?php echo (!empty($options['responsive']) && $options['responsive'] == 1 && !empty($options['ext_responsive']) && $options['ext_responsive'] == '1') ? 'true' : 'false'; ?>" data-header-resize="<?php echo $headerResize; ?>" data-header-color="<?php echo (!empty($options['header-color'])) ? $options['header-color'] : 'light' ; ?>" <?php echo (!empty($options['transparent-header']) && $options['transparent-header'] == '1') ? null : 'data-transparent-header="false"'; ?> data-smooth-scrolling="<?php echo $options['smooth-scrolling']; ?>" data-permanent-transparent="<?php echo $perm_trans; ?>" data-responsive="<?php echo (!empty($options['responsive']) && $options['responsive'] == 1) ? '1'  : '0' ?>" >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First debug the page source via CTRL+U or view source options from browser, what you see there? follow this google link for further steps based on your output https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6107056?hl=en&rd=1

Comment: keep in mind that class ="XXXXX" should contain double quotes, might be that causing issue?  like this can workout <body <?php="" body_class();="" ?="">> if its not printing at all maybe appending via functions.php using a hook can do the trick.